# How replace create java Thread by Kotlin's coroutines?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I'm a new in Kotlin's coroutines.

Here code with classic **Thread**:

```
 import com.google.gson.JsonElement
    import com.google.gson.JsonObject
    import com.google.gson.JsonParser
    import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
    import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    import okhttp3.*
    import okio.ByteString
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

    object BithumbSocketListener : WebSocketListener() {

        override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
            super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
            Thread {
                оkHttpClient.newWebSocket(wsRequest, BithumbSocketListener)
            }.start()
        }

        override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
            super.onMessage(webSocket, text)
            logger.debug("ws_onMessage: text = $text")
        }

    }

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        currenciesList = currencies.split(",")
        currenciesList.forEach {
            OkHttpClient().newWebSocket(wsRequest, BithumbSocketListener)
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have list of currencies (`currenciesList`). I iterate it and call `newWebSocket` for **every** item of list. As you can see `BithumbSocketListener` is a **singleton**.

If has some problem with web socket then call callback method `onFailure` and I create new web socket in separate java thread:

```
        Thread {
            оkHttpClient.newWebSocket(wsRequest, BithumbSocketListener)
}.start()
```

Nice. It's work fine.
But I want replace this code by **Kotlin coroutines**.
How I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're processing an async stream of messages, you should port it to coroutines by implementing an actor, such as

```
val wsActor: SendChannel<String> = actor {
    for (msg in channel) {
        logger.info("Another message is in: ${msg}")
    }
}
```

From the type of `wsActor` you can see you're supposed to send messages to it. This is where the bridging code comes in:

```
class BithumbSocketListener(
    private val chan: Channel<String>
) : WebSocketListener() {
    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        chan.send(text)
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
        оkHttpClient.newWebSocket(wsRequest, this)
    }
}
```

Note that, compared to your code, I don't start any new threads for retrying. This has nothing to do with porting to coroutines, your code doesn't need it either. `newWebSocket` is an async call that returns immediately.

Finally, start the websockets for each currency:

```
currenciesList.forEach {
    OkHttpClient().newWebSocket(wsRequest, BithumbSocketListener(wsActor)
}
```